# I'm getting an error with calling a method from another class

Tags: java

I know this gets asked alot but I can't find a solution to my problem. I assume my arguments are wrong in some way.

```
public class ImageFileHandler extends FileHandler {


public void displayImage() {
    //Displaying an image
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.add(picLabel);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(),
            img.getHeight()));
    frame.add(jPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I want to call this displayImage() method in the following class.

```
public class FileApplicationTester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedImage img;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Documents\\University\\Year_3\\Advanced Programming\\Week3\\supplementary materials-20190206\\images.jpeg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageFileHandler Display = new ImageFileHandler();
    ImageFileHandler.displayImage();

}
```

}

I'm getting an error with `ImageFileHandler.displayImage();`Tells me that the displayImage method needs to be static, but I don't want it to be static to that class right?

Comment: Replace `ImageFileHandler.displayImage();` with `Display.displayImage();`?

Comment: `Display.displayImage()` - probably want to call your variable `display` instead of `Display` as variables in Java should really start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your created instance of ImageFileHandler is called Display
So use it like this instead :  `Display.displayImage();`

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you tried to do

```
Display.displayImage();
```